# sort select element options and preserve focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, select

I am trying to write script that will sort all select elements on page and preserve selected element selected. I have worked and implemented function given below. this function works well for sorting but lost focus of selected Text, because source of rendered page suggest that earlier selected item is still selected but focus is set to last item.

```
       var bindSortselect= function(){
           $("select").each(function(){
               $(this).html($(this).children("option").sort(function (a, b) {
                 if (a.text.toUpperCase() == b.text.toUpperCase()) return 0;
                 if (a.text.toUpperCase() < b.text.toUpperCase()) return -1;
                 if (a.text.toUpperCase() > b.text.toUpperCase()) return 1;
               }));
          });
        };
```

Any Idea would be appreciated?

Comment: Record focus and reapply it?

Comment: how? Can you provide updated script? or Change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to retain the selected `option` and set it again after you sort the `options`. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZy43/2/).